# StreamPlot Label for General Parameter

Tags: plotting

I have a simple DEQ:

$$y'(t) = y + C$$

for a constant $C$. It turns out that the equilibrium point of this DEQ is $-C$.

I can use the `StreamPlot` command to plot the direction field for 'any' value of $C$, for example, for $C = 2$:

```
 StreamPlot[{1, y + 2}, {t, -4, 4}, {y, -8,  4}]
```

The `StreamPlot` is:

[image]

This `StreamPlot` would look exactly like this for any value of $C$.

is there some way to show the y-axis as a $C$ instead of $-2$ and to show the other values as $C \pm <\rm{offset}>$. That is, the point $-4$ is shown as $C-2$, the point $-2$ is shown as $C$, the point 0 is shown as $C+2$, etc. In other words, the y-axis values are shown as a function of the general equilibrium point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result using the `CustomTicks` package, which is part of the `LevelScheme` package that is available at http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/

The `CustomTicks` package lets you specify the desired TickLabelFunction for each axis:

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"]

StreamPlot[{1, y + 2}, {t, -4, 4}, {y, -8, 4}, 
  FrameTicks -> {
    {LinTicks[-8, 4, TickLabelFunction -> ("C " <> 
       Which[
         # == 0, "",
         # < 0,  "- " <> ToString@Abs@#, 
         # > 0,  "+ " <> ToString@#
       ]&@Round[# + 2] &)
    ], Automatic},
    {Automatic, Automatic}
    }
]
```

[image]